# Sublime text 2 - find file by class name in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When you press `Ctrl+p` Sublime will open popup when you can easily find the file. Sublime auto detect the file location in both situation when you press `/` or space between file path parts.

In Zend Framework all classes has name within follow template: `Namespace_Module_Other_Part_Of_Class_Location`, how can I make Sublime understand the `_` as a path separator when I press `Ctrl+p` and copy past the class name there?

So the above class should be recognized on location: `Project/Namespace/Module/Other/Part/Of/Class/Location.php`

[image: Sublime Ctrl+p screenshot]

I'm still looking for the solution of it. Even if the file search is hard-coded in Sublime 3, and you have a workaround to make it works, maybe to write some plugin? you are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Use space instead of _ ?

Comment: Please read the question, I know that I can use space or '/', but the question is, how can I make sublime understand the '_'. Thank you.

Comment: You don't. This functionality is hard-coded to Sublime Text 2. Why would you want to type _ when you can type space? Sounds like you have some kind of wrong approach for looking classes in your project and you are trying to force the editor to do something where a different approach is available.

Comment: Because I would like to copy class name, past it there and find the file. Right know I need to manually type with spaces, or copy/past and replace "_" with spaces.

Comment: I'm still looking for the solution of this

Comment: So basically you're looking for a way to convert underscores to spaces when you copy a class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple plugin and key binding. Select **`Tools -> New Plugin...`** and replace the contents with the following:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class UnderscoreToSpaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command('copy')
        clipboard = sublime.get_clipboard()
        clipboard = clipboard.replace('_', ' ')
        sublime.set_clipboard(clipboard)
```

Save the file as `Packages/User/underscore_to_space.py` where `Packages` is the folder opened when clicking on **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**.

Next, create a custom key binding for the command. Select **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`** and add the following:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "underscore_to_space" }
```

If the file is empty when you open it, surround the above line with square brackets `[ ]`. Save the file (it will automatically save to the correct location), and you're all set.

Now, all you need to do is select the text you want to convert, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. This will copy the text to the clipboard, replace the underscores with spaces, and put the modified text back in the clipboard. You can now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open `Goto Anything...` and paste in the modified text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

If you prefer to have the underscores replaces with forward slashes `/`, just change the `clipboard.replace()` arguments from `('_', ' ')` to `('_', '/')`.

Answer (score 1):

To get to the class definition you are looking for there exist several plugins doing "code intelligence". The plugins are language specific.

The most popular is [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel/) which provides *Jump to symbol definition* functionality. SublimeCodeIntel claims to do this for PHP too. However, who to setup this for your project should be another question.

Some more options for possible source code static analysis in Sublime Text 2  in this blog post:

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm asking for, but it could be as an alternative. Thank you.