# sublime text 2 GotoAnything - extend to recognize different separator

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I work with Laravel quite a bit, which uses . separators in many places to show directory levels in the code

ex: /admin/users/list inside the code might be represented as:

```
View::make('admin.users.list.blade.php');
```

To be able to quickly find this file via Control+P, I'd like to be able to just copy/paste 'admin.users.list' into GotoAnything search to find the file. However, it does not recognize the . as a separator and so I have to remove them.

Question: is there a way to tell ST2 to recognize the . as a file separator?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to change Sublime's definition of a path separator, as that is hard-coded. However, my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26444033/1426065) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18151570/1426065) describes a simple plugin and key mapping that will allow you to copy `admin.users.list`, and change it to the space-separated string `admin users list` which can then be directly pasted into Goto Anything. Briefly, the plugin is (modified to split on `.` instead of `_` is:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class UnderscoreToSpaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command('copy')
        clipboard = sublime.get_clipboard()
        clipboard = clipboard.replace('.', ' ')
        sublime.set_clipboard(clipboard)
```

Create the plugin and assign the key binding as detailed in the previous answer, and everything should work just fine. If you're bothered about the class and command name, change the class definition above to `DotToSpaceCommand`, the `.py` file to `Packages/User/dot_to_space.py`, and the key binding command to `dot_to_space`.